# Permissions declaration on Google when using Cordova BLE plugin

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, location, bluetooth-lowenergy

I updated my application and submitted it to Google for publication on the Play store.  Google wants me to fill in a Permissions Declaration form for coarse location permissions.  Coarse location permission appears to be required by blue tooth communications for a reason not understood by me.

My application itself does not use any location information.  I am trying to fill out the declaration as best I can but it is also requiring a 30 second video targeting consumers letting them know what and why location is being used.

Does anyone have insight into how to explain this to consumers?

Comment: "Coarse location permission appears to be required by blue tooth communications for a reason not understood by me" -- apps that scan for BLE devices may be able to identify the device's approximate location, if the app finds a BLE device whose MAC address is in a list of known fixed-location BLE devices.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  Not sure what to send as a video to Google to get approval but I will think of something.